# ExoPlayer Step one frame at a time

Tags: android, video, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a button that enables the user to skip the video by one frame at a time, not one second, but one frame.

Is there a way to do this with ExoPlayer?

Right now I'm getting the frame rate via MediaExtractor, and then doing a `seekTo(currentPosition + frameInMilliseconds)`.
But the `seekTo` function is slow, it delays about 1 second to actually show the frame

Answer (score 0):

There’s no out of the box way to do this for streaming.

If you are looking for this kind of experience I would recommend heading over to https://movi.ai to get your hands on our cross platform solution with this ready out of the box.